Do I need to manually disconnect signals if I am going to call deleteLater on a PyQt widget?
I have a QMainWidnow that spawns a number of different dialog boxes, I have been manually disconnecting all the signals before deleting the dialogs. Is this necessary, or are they cleaned up by the garbage collector or the PyQt backend?
class AlignmentStationInterface(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        add_button = QPushButton("Add Position")
        add_button.clicked.connect(self.add_position)
        self.position_builder_dialog = None

    def add_position(self):
        print('write new location')
        if self.new_position_builder_popup is not None:
            return
        self.position_builder_dialog = PositionBuilderDialog()
        self.position_builder_dialog.new_position_return.connect(self.save_position)
        self.position_builder_dialog.finished.connect(self.cleanup_dialog)

    def cleanup_dialog(self):
        # Are these disconnect lines necessary?
        self.position_builder_dialog.new_position_return.disconnect(self.save_position)
        self.position_builder_dialog.finished.disconnect(self.cleanup_dialog)
        self.position_builder_dialog.deleteLater()

    def save_position(self):
        pass
        

I expect that the backend takes care of things but I am worried about memory leaks.

Signals will be automatically disconnected when the objects are deleted, but if the slot forms a closure it could keep some objects alive unexpectedly (for more details, see this answer). Your example doesn't form any closures, but it is buggy in a different way. Calling deleteLater won't reset position_builder_dialog to None, so the PyQt wrapper will be kept alive, even though the C++ part has been deleted.

In theory, it's not necessary, but it depends.
Signals are normally disconnected automatically whenever one of their parts are destroyed: as long as the signals are connected to a function of a destroyed QObject, they are usually automatically disconnected upon deletion.
But you need to remember that using a Python binding such as PyQt (and PySide) you always end up with two objects: the "Python object" and the "Qt object" (the one existing in the "C++ world").
This means that Python objects and Qt objects can have different lifespans:

a Python object could be garbage collected because its reference count is down to 0, but its C++ counterpart could still exist (normally, because it has a QObject parent);
likewise, a C++ object could be destroyed, but the Python reference will still be alive and theoretically functional;

Your code is exemplary: you are creating a python reference to a Qt wrapped object, but deleteLater() will only destroy the C++ counterpart, because self.position_builder_dialog.deleteLater() will not delete the self.position_builder_dialog object in the Python interpreter.
In fact, if the button is clicked again after cleanup_dialog() is called (calling add_position() in turn), nothing will happen because self.new_position_builder_popup is not None. While the C++ object has been destroyed, the Python reference still exists.
In theory, even after the dialog has been actually destroyed (with deleteLater()), you could still call methods of PositionBuilderDialog as long as they don't rely on Qt functions strictly related to that dialog. That's because those methods exist in the Python namespace, and they still "make sense".
Let's suppose the following basic example:
class PositionBuilderDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.value = ''
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.edited)

    def edited(self, text):
        self.value = text

Then consider the following situation:
class AlignmentStationInterface(QMainWindow):
    ...
    def add_position(self):
        print('write new location')
        if self.new_position_builder_popup is not None:
            print(self.new_position_builder_popup.value)
            print(self.new_position_builder_popup.lineEdit)
            print(self.new_position_builder_popup.lineEdit.text())
            return
        ...

After the button has been clicked once and the dialog has been closed (then deleted in cleanup_dialog()), clicking the button will do the following:

enter the if block, because new_position_builder_popup is not None;
print the content of the dialog's value;
print the Python reference to the lineEdit object;
crash because text() would attempt to call the related function of the wrapped C++ object, which doesn't exist anymore;

In your case, you don't need to disconnect the signals, but you do need to actually remove the Python reference:
    def cleanup_dialog(self):
        self.position_builder_dialog.deleteLater()
        self.position_builder_dialog = None

In principle, calling deleteLater() is normally required, but also ensuring that all Python references are also deleted is usually recommended. The former will actually delete the real Qt object (which will free up much of the memory the program is being using for it), while the latter is usually required mostly for reliable code: before worrying about memory leaks, you should worry about usage of object references.
Note that signal connections can create further closures in some cases (especially when using lambdas), meaning that the Python objects could still exist even if they have been theoretically destroyed. Remember that you can never completely rely on garbage collection when dealing with wrapped objects in bindings, and that lifespans of objects may be completely inconsistent.
Take the following code, based on the above:
    def add_position(self):
        dialog = PositionBuilderDialog(self) # note the "self" argument
        dialog.show()

In the Python world, that would automatically garbage collect dialog. Still, the dialog will be shown without problems. That's because the dialog has been created with a parent, which ensures that it will always be kept alive as long as the parent it. Qt doesn't know anything about Python, it only knows that the dialog has a parent, and then it will not destroy it, until that parent is.

I've always seen in the API that you could set parents for Qt Objects, but I always passed None to that parameter. I never had worry about C++ Objects getting destroyed earlier, or Python Objects getting garbage collected and C++ Objects still existing in memory because of that, probably. So, about your add_position example, you can actually just use a global list to keep a reference out of the garbage collector's sight. Of course, you'd have to manage the list yourself in that case. But, as a bonus, you'd be dealing with python objects only, leaving C++ Objects out of the equation.

@CarlHR That approach would be quite risky, though. For slightly complex programs, that would mean to always choose when an object should be added to that global list (and considering why it would/wouldn't a good reason). Not to mention the fact that using a more fragmented code (internal modules) would incredibly complicate things. The reality is that each object should require proper consideration about its persistence in both Python and C++. When dealing with child widgets, we can normally leave that to basic Qt parent/child management, but more complex subclasses are different beasts.

Good to know. My apps were never that big, so that's probably it. And I just used this hack for avoiding calling exec on QDialogs or storing fire n forget QThreads. I never meant to use it for everything, just for resources that I wanted to avoid being garbage collected.
